# "Anchoring" in Report Viewer

Tags: .net, anchor, reportviewer

I have a report that contains a matrix that is displayed on a 8.5 by 14 in page. Normally, I would strech the detail section up to 13in(14 - margins) and display the page number at the far right. I would also strech the title in the page header. However, when I do that, I always get an empty page, and more is I actually got enough rows to strech over two pages vertically. It seems that the empty space between my matrix and the end of the page is at cause here because if I narrow the detail section to only the matrix definition, while keeping the 14 inches page, I don't get that last page.

Is there any way for me to put the page number at the far right while not having the extra page and how ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found out what I wanted I might as well write it down. There is a property call ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace which does exactly that.